# How to apply regular expressions to get a number from a dynamic string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a variable that can contain a few variations, it also contains a number which can be any number.

The variations:

```
($stuksprijs+9.075);
($stuksprijs-9.075);
($stuksprijs*9.075);

($m2+9.075);
($m2-9.075);
($m2*9.075);

($o+9.075);
($o-9.075);
($o*9.075);
```

These are the only variations except for the numbers in it, they can change. And I need that number.

So there can be:

```
($m2+5);
```

or

```
($o+8.25);
```

or

```
($stuksprijs*3);
```

How can I get the number from those variations? How can I get the 9.075 or 5 or 8.25 or 3 from my above examples with regular expression?

I am trying to fix this with PHP, my variable that contains the string is: `$explodeberekening[1]`

I read multiple regex tutorials and got it to work for a single string that never changes, but how can I write a regex to get the number from above variations?

Comment: Could you show the pattern that failed for you please?

Comment: Would [`^\(\$(?:stuksprijs|m2|o)[+*-](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\);$`](https://regex101.com/r/OkXEwf/1) ,where your number will be contained by 1st capture group, work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment, which seems to have worked, you can try:

```
^\(\$(?:stuksprijs|m2|o)[+*-](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\);$
```

The number is captured in the 1st capture group. See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIwXWj/1).

A quick breakdown:

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `\(\$` - Literally match "($".
- `(?:` - Open a non-capture group to list alternation:

  - `stuksprijs|m2|o` - Match one of these literal alternatives.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `[+*-]` - Match one of the symbols from the character-class.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits.
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - Extra optional non-capture group to match a literal dot and 1+ digits.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.
- `\);` - Literally match ");".
- `$` - End string anchor.